# Strawberry Perl - Net::Server test hangs during install

Tags: perl, cpan, strawberry-perl

While installing Net::Server, the tests hang on 4/5, and the install blocks until I send a break signal. I've tried googling, but haven't been able to find anything relevant.

I'm using Strawberry Perl 5.12.2 on Windows XP

Install output:

```
cpan> install Net::Server
Running install for module 'Net::Server'
Running make for R/RH/RHANDOM/Net-Server-0.99.tar.gz
  Has already been unwrapped into directory C:\strawberry\cpan\build\Net-Server-
0.99-lExqFv
  Has already been made
Running make test
C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0,
'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t
t/Options.t ............... ok
t/Port_Configuration.t .... ok
t/Server_BASE.t ........... ok
t/Server_Fork.t ........... ok
t/Server_http.t ........... 4/5 Terminating on signal SIGINT(2)
```

Comment: One thing you might try is to run `C:\strawberry\perl\bin\perl.exe "-MExtUtils::Command::MM" "-e" "test_harness(0,
'blib\lib', 'blib\arch')" t/*.t` yourself, on the command line.  Perhaps it would print extra error information or perhaps there is an option to do so.

Comment: Other things you could try to get more info `>cpan look Net::Server`, then `% prove --lib -v t/Server_http.t`. Or you're familiar with the perl debugger, `% perl -d -I lib t/Server_http.t`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[The test](http://cpansearch.perl.org/src/RHANDOM/Net-Server-0.99/t/Server_http.t) is using [alarm](http://p3rl.org/alarm) which has [portability problems](http://p3rl.org/port#alarm). Net::Server was [not at all successfully tested on Windows](http://matrix.cpantesters.org/?dist=Net-Server+0.99).

The author should write the test in a portable way. [File a bug](https://rt.cpan.org/Ticket/Create.html?Queue=Net-Server) with the problem description.

Comment: Thanks for the test report - I proceedded with notest, and it works well enough for my application. I'll file a bug with cpan if one doesn't already exist.

Comment: You can install with a no test option (using cpanm): cpanm Net::Server -n